# Java Recursion with char

Tags: java, recursion, char

I want to print all of the letters between two letters using recursion and this is how I did it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class q24 {

  public static void between(char a, char b) {
    if (a==b) {
      System.out.println(b);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(a+1);
      between((char)(a+1), b);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    between('e','l');
  }
}
```

but it's printing:

```
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
l
```

how can I make it print letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing arithmetic operations on `char` (like `a + 1`), the result value is automatically converted to `int`.

In order to have the result of the arithmetic operation printed as `char`, you will have to do an explicit cast:

```
System.out.println((char) (a+1));
```

Moreover, I think you have an error in your implementation : the last character (`b`) will be printed twice - before the last recursion call, and at the recursion bottom. You can fix it like:

```
public static void between(char a, char b) {
    System.out.println(a);
    if (a < b){
        between((char) (a+1), b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `a+1`in `System.out.println(a+1);` it is effectively converting char to int and therefore it is printing ints.

Change it to this :- `System.out.println((char)(a+1));`